# Tab title is not showing completely in material design library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) and I changed the code of `setupTabIcons` in `CustomViewIconTextTabsActivity`:

```
private void setupTabIcons() {  
    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText("PROPOSAL");
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setText("MY JOBS");
    tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_call, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

    TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabThree.setText("MESSAGE");
    tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

    TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabFour.setText("PROFILE");
    tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
}
```

PROPOSAL is not showing completely..it is showing PROPOSA at first tab

I try to increase and decrease text size of textview... how show complete text in tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **activity_custom_view_icon_text_tabs.xml** and change the `tabMode` of `TabLayout` to `scrollable`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods which I found

first one is

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
```

use this as a theme like

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

and Second : use    `app:tabMode="scrollable"`
like:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
         app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```